# Simulation of Wired Network in OMNET++ using INET framework - UDP

Tags: udp, simulation, omnet++, packet, wireless

So, I am trying to do a very basic wired network simulation  (later on I will add wireless nodes) in OMNET++:
**packet type:** UDP
**Traffic Type:** Video Streaming
**OMNET version**:6.0.1
**INET version:** 4.5

The simulation ends without running properly and it just says "simulation timed ended" when I run it. There is no error. Thus, no results are being recorded either.
[image]

The **log** also shows me this:

> > INFO (Tcp)GiB.standardHost1[20].tcp: GiB.standardHost1[20].tcp: finishing with 0 connections open.
> > INFO (Tcp)GiB.standardHost1[21].tcp: GiB.standardHost1[21].tcp: finishing with 0 connections open.
> > INFO (Tcp)GiB.standardHost1[22].tcp: GiB.standardHost1[22].tcp: finishing with 0 connections open.
> > INFO (Tcp)GiB.standardHost1[23].tcp: GiB.standardHost1[23].tcp: finishing with 0 connections open.
> > INFO (Tcp)GiB.standardHost1[24].tcp: GiB.standardHost1[24].tcp: finishing with 0 connections open.
> > INFO (Tcp)GiB.server.tcp: GiB.server.tcp: finishing with 0 connections open.

here is my **.NED** file:

```
import inet.networklayer.configurator.ipv4.Ipv4NetworkConfigurator;
import inet.node.ethernet.EthernetSwitch;
import inet.node.inet.StandardHost;
import ned.DatarateChannel;

//WIRED-SCENARIO
network GiB
{
    parameters:
        int numHosts;
        @display("bgb=650,520");
        @statistic[endToEndDelay](title="end-to-end delay"; source="messageAge(rcvdPk)"; unit=s; record=histogram,vector; interpolationmode=none);
        @statistic[throughput](title="throughput"; unit=bps; source="throughput(rcvdPk)"; record=histogram,vector);

    types:
        channel Ether1000m extends DatarateChannel
        {
            datarate = 1000Mbps;
            delay = 0.1us;
        }
    submodules:
        standardHost[numHosts]: StandardHost {
            @display("p=85,179");
        }
        standardHost1[numHosts]: StandardHost {
            @display("p=302,374");
        }
        server: StandardHost {
            @display("p=531,67;i=device/server");
        }
        configurator: Ipv4NetworkConfigurator {
            @display("p=46,39");
        }
        centerSwitch: EthernetSwitch {
            @display("p=418,146");
        }
        ethernetSwitch1: EthernetSwitch {
            @display("p=256,146");
            
                
        }
        ethernetSwitch2: EthernetSwitch {
            @display("p=341,260");
            
        }
    connections:
        server.ethg++ <--> Ether1000m <--> centerSwitch.ethg++;
        ethernetSwitch1.ethg++ <--> Ether1000m <--> centerSwitch.ethg++;
        ethernetSwitch2.ethg++ <--> Ether1000m <--> centerSwitch.ethg++;
        for i=0..numHosts-1 {
            ethernetSwitch1.ethg++ <--> Ether1000m <--> standardHost[i].ethg++;
            standardHost1[i].ethg++ <--> Ether1000m <--> ethernetSwitch2.ethg++;
        }
        
}
```

and **ini** file:

```
[General]
network = GiB
#wiredscenario
sim-time-limit = 5400s

**.numHosts = ${5..25 step 10}
*.*.numUdpApps = 1

**.channel.throughput.statistic-recording = true
**.channel.throughput.result-recording-modes = all
**.*.vector-recording = true
**.*.vector-recording-intervals = 0..900
**.*.scalar-recording = true

[Config UDP]

**.standardHost[*].udpApp[*].typename = "UdpVideoStreamClient"
**.standardHost[*].udpApp[*].serverAddress = "server"
**.standardHost[*].udpApp[*].serverPort = 1000
**.standardHost[*].udpApp[*].startTime = 5s


**.standardHost1[*].udpApp[*].typename = "UdpVideoStreamClient"
**.standardHost1[*].udpApp[*].serverAddress = "server"
**.standardHost1[*].udpApp[*].serverPort = 1000

**.server.udpApp[*].typename = "UdpVideoStreamServer"
**.server.udpApp[*].localPort = 1000
**.server.udpApp[*].sendInterval = 0.001s
**.server.udpApp[*].packetLen = 1400B
**.server.udpApp[*].videoSize = 1Gb
```

1. Am I doing it right?
2. If yes, then please guide how to fix this scenario
3. If no, then please correct.

Please I need help. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems in your `omnetpp.ini`:

1. `INET` uses `numApps` instead of `numUdpApps` or `numTcpApps`.
2. `StandardHost` has `app[]` for storing application - neither `udpApp[]` nor `tcpApp[]`.

Reference: [INET NED Documentation - StandardHost](https://doc.omnetpp.org/inet/api-current/neddoc/inet.node.inet.StandardHost.html)

So the corrected `omnetpp.ini` should look like this:

```
[General]
network = GiB
sim-time-limit = 5400s

**.numHosts = ${5..25 step 10}

**.channel.throughput.statistic-recording = true
**.channel.throughput.result-recording-modes = all
**.*.vector-recording = true
**.*.vector-recording-intervals = 0..900
**.*.scalar-recording = true

[Config UDP]
**.standardHost[*].numApps = 1
**.standardHost[*].app[*].typename = "UdpVideoStreamClient"
**.standardHost[*].app[*].serverAddress = "server"
**.standardHost[*].app[*].serverPort = 1000
**.standardHost[*].app[*].startTime = 5s

**.standardHost1[*].numApps = 1
**.standardHost1[*].app[*].typename = "UdpVideoStreamClient"
**.standardHost1[*].app[*].serverAddress = "server"
**.standardHost1[*].app[*].serverPort = 1000

**.server.numApps = 1
**.server.app[*].typename = "UdpVideoStreamServer"
**.server.app[*].localPort = 1000
**.server.app[*].sendInterval = 0.001s
**.server.app[*].packetLen = 1400B
**.server.app[*].videoSize = 1Gb
```

Moreover, in your NED file I suggest removing `@display` for hosts, because it results in displaying all hosts in the same place:

```
submodules:
 standardHost[numHosts]:  StandardHost;
 standardHost1[numHosts]: StandardHost;
```

Comment: It's working!!! Thank you so much. Appreciate it! :)

Comment: Could you please tell me that if I add 
 `*.*.numApps = 1` after this
`**.numHosts = ${5..25 step 10}` in `[General]`
and not like you did with each standardHosts/server i.e., 
`**.standardHost1[*].numApps = 1` 

I got following error which I couldn't understand:

Unable to determine type name for submodule app, missing entry GiB.centerSwitch.app[0].typename and no default value, at C:/Omnetv6/omnetpp-6.0.1/samples/inet4.4/src/inet/node/ ethernet/EthernetSwitch.ned:94 -- in module (omnetpp::cModule) GiB.centerSwitch (id=14)

This is why I changed it to udpApps

Comment: The generic model of switch in `INET` assumes that it may contain a TCP or UDP application. Therefore ``*.*.numApps = 1` results in setting one application for all hosts **as well as for all switches**. However, `omnetpp.ini` does not contain a typename of application for switches - therefore the error is generated. Usually we do not need switch's application, so I suggest setting the number of application only for `standardHost` and `standardHost1`.

Comment: Again, thanks a lot! One last question (I hope you don't mind, its hard to find someone who knows OMNET like you do). What if I try to create subnets (wired+wireless) in the above scenario. Do I need a router (submodule) to do that? or can I just use IPV4NetworkConfigurator and it will take care of the routing and subnetting?

Comment: `IPv4NetworkConfigurator` is responsible only for assigning addresses for hosts and routers. `IPv4NetworkConfigurator` does not transfer any packets. If your network is flat, router is not necessary.

Comment: Hi, can you please help me with this? I have tried @statistic[nameOfStatistic] for PacketLoss but still it doesn't come up in .anf. How to calculate it? I am unable to find enough information on this. Please help!

Also, which module filter or result name filter should I use to get the required result i.e., PacketLoss throughput and E2E delay (all these for each node respectively)? Thank you